# Symbols in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I thought I knew how the `{/Symbol x}` worked in gnuplot but I don't. I need to get a partial derivative symbol (utf8 code U+2202), and I can't. How could I do it. I haven't found anything online. This is the document settings:

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color font "Helvetica, 20"
set encoding utf8
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need to use a postscript terminal, use

```
{/Symbol \266}
```

Your gnuplot distribution should contain the file `ps_guide.ps`. That explains all the character codes available in postscript.

In general I would second Christoph's suggestion to use a cairo terminal. In combination with UTF-8 input encoding and a proper font you can easily include more characters in your output.

When I generate plots for inclusion in TeX documents, I tend to use the same font as the body text (in the example below "TeX Gyre Pagella")

```
set terminal pdfcairo enhanced color dashed font "TeX Gyre Pagella, 14" \
rounded size 16 cm, 9.6 cm
set encoding utf8
```

Comment: Thank you, I accept your answer for being more complete.

Comment: btw, is there any reason cairo terminal would be a better choice than epslatex terminal if I'm going to include all my results on a TeX document?

Comment: @MyUserIsThis In my opionion there is no simple answer to the question which is better. Both have their advantages and disadvantages. In general `cairo` can be simpler, while `epslatex` gives you the complete power of LaTeX formatting.

Comment: There is also a `cairolatex` terminal. But if you use TeX anyway, you don't have the problem with the characters.

Answer (score 2):

Use any of the cairo-based terminal (`pdfcairo` or `epscairo`) and insert the character directly into your script:

```
set encoding utf8

set terminal pdfcairo font ',20'
set output 'partial-derivative.pdf'
set xlabel '∂u/∂x'
plot x
```

[image]